# Copy assignment on a structure of references

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I have a struct of references and an array of that struct, I want to sort the array by some component of that struct but using `std::sort` gives me a `foo &foo::operator=(const foo &) attempting to reference a deleted function error` on Visual Studio

```
struct foo {
    double &x, &y;
};

foo arr[10];

std::sort(arr, arr + 10, [](const foo &a, const foo &b){ return a.x < b.x;});
```

I solved the error by making my own copy assignment operator

```
// inside the struct 'foo'
foo &operator=(const foo &a)
{
    /*
        assigning x to a.x and y to a.y would just change their values not the actual reference
        so I used std::move to actually change the references
    */

    *this = std::move(a);
     return *this;
}
```

and now I have a warning `foo::operator= : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow`

I'm looking for a solution that removes this warning

Comment: In C++, structures with references do not have a default assignment operator (and move-assignment operator, too). Full stop. Your explicit assignment operator invokes `*this`'s assignment operator. Which happens to be the very same assignment operator. Infinite recursion, and your compiler is smart enough to detect that. Can you explain what an assignment operator is supposed to accomplish for your structure, keeping in mind that you can't assign to references themselves in C++ (which is why there's no default assignment operator), you can only assign to what the references are referencing.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote in a comment:

> assigning x to a.x and y to a.y would just change their values not the actual reference
>   so I used std::move to actually change the references

So I see that you're under the impression that it's possible to "re-seat" references in C++. This is false. Once a reference has been initialized, you can only modify the referent.

If you want a reseatable reference, use a pointer instead:

```
struct foo {
    double* x;
    double* y;
};

foo arr[10];

std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](const foo &a, const foo &b){ return a->x < b->x;});
```

You could also use `std::reference_wrapper` to make it clear that `x` and `y` are non-null:

```
struct foo {
    std::reference_wrapper<double> x;
    std::reference_wrapper<double> y;
};

// I assume you have some strategy for initializing `arr`

std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](const foo &a, const foo &b){ return a.get().x < b.get().x;});
```

Comment: I know I can't re-seat a reference, but what about the whole object? Is that possible? I want the copy assignment to change the references, and I can do that by copying the object right?

Comment: @coconyat You can't re-seat objects. In some languages, you can re-seat variables, but only because those variables are actually mutable references to objects. C++ is not such a language. Also, copying the object would just give you a second object whose references had the same referents as the first object, so I am not sure how this would solve your problem.

Comment: I see, I understand now

Comment: @coconyat "*I know I can't re-seat a reference*" - then you just answered your own question. "*what about the whole object? Is that possible?*" - no. Only non-reference members can be copied/moved from one object to another. "*I want the copy assignment to change the references*" - asked and answered - it is not possible. "*I can do that by copying the object right?*" - no. Copying an object simply means to copy the object's members to another object's members. References can't be copied, only the things they are referencing can be.